# Fill object array inside of LINQ Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

How to fill `Object Array` inside a `LINQ Query`

Here is my data model

```
public class Test
    {
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Item[] Items { get; set; }
    }

 public class Item
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the Query

```
var data = from feed in feedXml.Descendants("channel")
                        select new Rss
                        {
                            Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
                            Link = feed.Element("link").Value,
                            Description = feed.Element("description").Value,
                            Items = // here i have to fill the array of items
                        };
```

**UPDATE**
xml formate

```
<channel>
  .....  
  <item>.....</item>
  <item>.....</item>
  <item>.....</item>
</channel>
<channel>
  .....  
  <item>.....</item>
  <item>.....</item>
  <item>.....</item>
</channel>
<channel>
  .....  
  <item>.....</item>
  <item>.....</item>
  <item>.....</item>
</channel>
```

Comment: provide your xml file format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to make another query inside of your query. For example if `channel` element contains `item` elements then you can do:

```
Items = feed.Elements("item")
           .Select(x => new Item { // set property values })
           .ToArray()
```

Update: It seems you are reading a `RSS` file, so your query should be something like this:

```
var data = from feed in feedXml.Descendants("channel")
            select new Rss
            {
                Title = (string) feed.Element("title"),
                Link = (string) feed.Element("link"),
                Description = (string) feed.Element("description"),
                Items = feed.Elements("item")
                    .Select(
                        x =>
                            new Item
                            {
                                Title = (string) x.Element("title"),
                                Link = (string) x.Element("link"),
                                Description = (string) x.Element("description"),
                                Guid = (string) x.Element("guid"),
                                PublishDate = (DateTime) x.Element("pubDate")
                            })
                    .ToArray()

            };
```

Also I have used explicit cast instead of trying to access `Value` property  directly to prevent `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @AhmadAbbasi actually I mean the item element's format.But that's ok see my update, if the element names are wrong you can change it.At least you must have an idea now :)